# How to get all available tax rates in a Commerce site?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, adjusters, tax

Is there a way to retrieve and loop through all the available tax rates that have been set up in Commerce 1?

I had thought I could loop through the adjusters like so;

```
{% for adjustment in cart.adjustments %}
    {{ adjustment.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

In fact, I'm doing this on one site with no problems but having just tried the same thing on another project I am running into errors. I'm guessing because no adjustments exist unless there is actually a cart object.

I am trying to retrieve its value in order to display the price including tax on my product page template. For this particular case I only have 1 tax rate, so there is no problem with regionality. I figured that I could loop through the adjuster, check the name and retrieve the value.

If there's another way to do this I'm all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Commerce 2**

```
{% set allTaxRates = craft.commerce.taxRates.allTaxRates() %}

{% for taxRate in allTaxRates %}
    {{ taxRate.name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

`taxRate` will be an instance of `craft\commerce\models\TaxRate`

---

**Commerce 1**

If you're looking to get all of the tax rates setup in Commerce from a template, something like this should work:

```
{% set allTaxRates = craft.commerce.getTaxRates() %}

{% for taxRate in allTaxRates %}
    {{ taxRate.name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

`taxRate` will be an instance of `Commerce_TaxRateModel`.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Is there a link to the docs for this? I knew there must be a way to do it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Nope... just looked at the code.  We've got a big push to improve the Commerce 2 docs we're working on, though.